# Julia not operator

Tags: julia

I am wondering if there is a way to use somesort of not operator with function such `ismissing()` or `isempty()`
For example, if I want to do something like this, How would I go about it.

```
x = Array[]
y = missing

if x not isempty(x)
    # do something
elif not ismissing(y)
    # do something
end
```

This is of course incorrect, and an empty array can be solved with `if length(x) >0`. But I am wondering if there is a way to do using with not-operator like in python. For example, In python numpy library I can do something like this to achieve this,

```
y = np.nan
if y is not np.nan:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the `!(x)` function, e.g. `!ismissing(x)`.